# How to install and configure a server with nginx + rails API under Windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, nginx

There are two questions:

1. How to deploy a part of the RAILS API application on the nginx server (via Windows), at the moment I have deployed only the client part written in Angular, now I need to display the data from the server side written in Rails.

   my **nginx.conf** file is bellow

```html
worker_processes  1;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        location / {
            root   html/dist;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html/dist;
        }     
    }
}
```

2. After updating the page, if the link is specified in about this format http://localhost/login, it will return an error 404 although it worked before updating. How can this be remedied?

Comment: After deploy rails app and have Ruby etc installed, you habe to set root to `/APPPATH/current/public`
If you&#39;re using passenger etc. enable it.
Follow some normal rails deploy guide ;) for example from Digital Ocean

Comment: And what if you use Puma?